# How many reflexive relation are there on a set with n elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

How many reflexive relation are there on a set with n elements ?

Comment: In here where I study maths, it's defined that a relation is a subset of Decartes product $A\times A$. So a reflexive relation is a subset contains all $(a,a)$. There are remaining $2^{n^2-n}$ ways to construct a subset

Comment: for symmetric and transitive and antisymmetric ?

Comment: @Salman If you keep pumping for more answers to other questions, I'll flag. If you have more questions, post as a new question.

Comment: Symmetric means if there is $(a,b)$ in the subset, there should also be $(b,a)$ (if $a\ne b$). Then you should see how many choice you have. ($2^n$ for $(a,a)$ and something divide $2$ for $(a,b)$)
Transitive is a little bit more tricky I think. But you should work by yourself and see what happen. Then you should ask by pointing out where you are stuck.

Answer (score 11):

Let $A$ be this set. Write $A\times A$ in a grid. If the square $(j,k)$ is marked, that means that $jRk$.

Since the relation is reflexive you must mark the main diagonal. They are $n$ squares. Now the question is: 'How many ways are there to mark or not the other squares of the grid?'. There are $n^2-n$ squares, and there are $2$ possibilities for each. Then, there are
$$2^{n^2-n}$$
possibilities.

Comment: for symmetric and transitive and antisymmetric ?

Comment: @Salman Don't get greedy, pumping for more answers to other questions. Your question was answered, and very well, at that. If you have another question, post it as a new question.